# How to put a paragraph in the center of a page inside a box?

Tags: positioning

I want to put the following paragraph in the center of a page inside a box. Please suggest how to do this.

```
Z.<x> = ZZ[] 

f = (x^3 - 45*x^2 - 11637*x - 344520) 

K.<a> = f.root_field()

K

L.<b> = K.galois_closure();L
```

Comment: If that's code, I think `verbatim` is the key-word here. You have lots of packages to frame verbatim environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, what is the center of a page and and a box in this case and what about math, hence this is only a suggestion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}


\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.2pt} % only to show horizozontal centering

\null\vfill

\noindent\null\hfil\framebox[8cm][l]{\vbox{
\obeylines\obeyspaces
Z. = ZZ[]

$f = (x^3 - 45*x^2 - 11637*x - 344520)$

\url{K. = f.root_field()}

K

\url{L. = K.galois_closure();L}
}}\hfil


\vfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some explanations. The `url` package gives us a simple way of obtaing underscore; `\obeylines` and `\obeyspaces` override standard TeX rules of treating line feeds and multiple spaces.

Comment: Can you please tell when to put \url ?

Comment: @Suman I have just enlarged the answer a bit.

Comment: I don't want so much spaces on both sides of the text inside the box ? Can you make the box more tighter ?

Comment: @Suman I have just changed to a new version.

Comment: Is the center of the box at the center of the text body area?

Comment: @Sigur Yes, modulo behaviour induced by `\topsep` et al.